# Unity - Shoot a bullet at last position of player

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemybullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform player;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

        Vector3 lastpos = player.position;

        Destroy(gameObject, 4f);
    }
```

```
gets last pos of player
```

```
 void Update()
 {
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, 10f);
 }
```

go towards player

I want it to shoot the direction of player and its not letting me use lastpos in the movetowards function

Comment: maybe the gameobject was not tagged, FindGameObjectWithTag returns null if no GameObject was found. You can try GameObject.Find("GameobjectName") to find a gameobject in the scene https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html. If that is not the problem please share the detail of the error you're having

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `scope` of your variables.

```
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

    Vector3 lastpos = player.position;

    Destroy(gameObject, 4f);
}
```

As you can see here, you have *Declared* your variable within a `{...}` (scope) which means the variable will only be visible within the scope it was created in (and will actually be destroyed as soon as execution leaves the `{...}`

To fix this you need to declare your variable in scope of the whole class

```
public Vector3 lastpos;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

    lastpos = player.position;

    Destroy(gameObject, 4f);
}
```

You will now be able to access `lastpos` from anywhere within your class (or even outside your class)

Comment: so I did that and I still cant use it i have no idea why

Comment: @Micnasr what do you mean by you can't use it?

Comment: If you do this you need to change to `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, lastpos, 10f);` in the update method